# How to find AWS Load Balancer ARN from its name with python api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, elastic-load-balancer

Given a load balancer name, is it possible to find its ARN with AWS API?
The closest I see is the describe_load_balancers function, but its output doesn't include ARN. Am I missing something simple?

Full context: The script adds "DDoSAttackBitsPerSecond" metrics to a AWS Dashboard, and metric description includes the ARN of the load balancer as one of its dimensions.

Any suggestions appreciated,

Mike

Comment: The ARN is returned for application load balancers, not for classic load balancers. Is generating the ARN dynamically an option for you? If so, the ELB arn looks like this: `arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:{region}:{account-id}:loadbalancer/{name}`. You know the name and region of the load balancer. To get the account number, invoke the `GetCallerIdentity` API (under sts).

Comment: I was using boto3.client('elb'), which doesn't return ARN, instead of boto3.client('elbv2'), which does. Thanks for quick response though.

Answer (score 4):

Doh, I was using boto3.client('elb'), which doesn't return ARN, instead of boto3.client('elbv2'), which does. I hope someone will find this useful...

Comment: `elbv2` is for application load balancers only. `elb` is used for classic load balancers. These are different.

Comment: And those are application lb I'm dealing with, at least at this point.